# Assign roles at registration

Tags: 8, users

I am trying to assign a user role at registration using Webforms in Drupal 8. Is this possible or is there another form module that would do it better? I have two user roles 'Venue' and Artist' which will be used throughout the site still using Webforms to enter data specific to user role. New to D8. Thank you.

Comment: You manually create the user with data submitted trough a webform?

Comment: Thank you. I want the user role (either Venue or Artist) to be assigned automatically when the Webforms form has been submitted during registration. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Oneway you can do is using hook_form_alter()

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
     foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
        if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
          $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = '_add_role_submit';
        }
      }
}
/**
 * Implements submit to set role to user.
 */
function _add_role_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
// HERE YOU CAN SET ANY ROLE FOR USER.
}
```

Another way is using hook_user_insert()

```
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;
function MYMODULE_user_insert(UserInterface $user) {
  // HERE YOU CAN SET ANY ROLE FOR USER.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above form alter solution didn't work for me and I don't want to use hook_user_insert() as I want to assign the role only when the user is created from user/register form, not from Admin interface. So I found a solution myself and sharing here if it helps any one else.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function member_portal_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    array_unshift($form['#validate'], "_add_default_role_validate"); 
}
/**
 * Implements _add_default_role_validate.
 */
function _add_default_role_validate(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Add default roles here
    $form_state->setValue('roles', [
       'authenticated',
        'venue_creator',
        'supplier_creator' 
    ]);
}
```